# How can I set opacity in a ListContourPlot?

Tags: plotting

I want to put two different ListContourPlots atop of each other using Show[plot1,plot2]. But I want the top layer to be somewhat transparent.

I am considering two options:

The first one, is it possible to have a ListContourPlot not with a fully filled area but having the area consist of shaded or criss cross lines.

The other idea is to set a value for Opacity, but right now I cannot find out how to have my cod look like

```
plot1=ListContourPlot[data,  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]
```

But it this one does not work for some reason.

Can you help me?

Comment: Try `ContourShading` and `ContourStyle`. Examples can easily be found on the Docs page for `ListContourPlot`.

Comment: But how do I add transparency to the Plot whit these options?

Comment: `Plot` has `PlotStyle` and `FillingStyle`, please read the Docs!

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took some deep digging and I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6570997/5201169).

Generate two plots:

```
plot1 = ListContourPlot[
  Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}], 
  ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"]
plot2 = ListContourPlot[
  Table[Sin[i + j], {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}], 
  BaseStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.3]]]
```

[image]

In the second the opacity is introduced via `BaseStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.3]]`.

Now, `Show` doesn't work so use `Overlay`:

```
Overlay[{plot1, plot2}]
```

[image]

which does not look clear at all, so maybe a different way to present your data would be more suitable.